# Is there an "example use" or "example" Javadoc tag?

Tags: java, documentation, javadoc

Is there a tag (or a conventional custom tag) for the Javadoc tool that can be used to explain an illustrative use case of a given method?

Example:

```
/**
 * Returns the sum of all the elements in an integer array.
 * 
 * @param numbers Array of integers to be summed.
 * @example {@code sum(1, 2, 3); -> 6}
 */
public int sum(int... numbers) {

    int tally = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        tally += numbers[i]
    }
    
    return tally
}
```

In the simple example above, the @example tag provides a quick demonstration of the method.

Comment: [Documentation Comment Specification for the Standard Doclet (JDK 21)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/specs/javadoc/doc-comment-spec.html) - maybe `@snippet`  (Java18 or later)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no such tag, although you should check out the latest extensions to the JavaDoc tool that allows to add sample code to the JavaDoc documentation (keyword: `@snippet`).

If this is not what you want, or you want it differently, you can implement your own JavaDoc tag quite easily.

You can find documentation related to `@snippet` here:

- [Documentation Comment Specification for the Standard Doclet](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/specs/javadoc/doc-comment-spec.html)
- [JEP 413](https://openjdk.org/jeps/413)
- [JavaDoc Code Snippet API - Sip of Java](https://inside.java/2022/04/04/sip46/)
- [Java Magazine: Javadoc documents are great – and better than ever with `@snippets`](https://blogs.oracle.com/javamagazine/post/java-javadoc-snippet)

Have fun!